# Compensation to start-up employees upon company's exit

Tags: startup, compensation

Start-up I am working for is being acquired. What compensation should I expect not including equity I was given when joined the company, if any?  And if I am offered such compensation, how can I evaluate whether it's fair for me as an employee?

Contract I signed when joined the company does not cover this case.

Comment: Fair for you or fair for the company purchasing or fair for the person selling up?

Comment: Whatever was written in your contract.

Comment: Seems like it depends on the aquirer, no?  If they're aquihiring, then you might be in for a good retention bonus; if they're aquiring you for the purpose of your IP, or for removing a competitor, or to specifically aquihire the head of the startup ... then I hope your equity is good.  Either way not really something we can answer here.

Comment: Yeah, expect nothing. At best, they may offer you a retention package to incentivize you to stay with the company.

Comment: appreciate some feedback from those who downvoted or voted to close

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Nothing**

There's no "free money truck" that comes around for acquisitions or IPOs. The way people get compensated during an exit are:

1. Any equity shares you have vested (and exercised, if they're options) may be either cashed out or transformed into shares of the new company.
2. You may be offered a bonus of some mix of your unvested equity and new stock in the new company, typically as "golden handcuffs" vesting over a time period, to keep you on.
3. There is a very slim chance of a raise or title bump or something if you're being merged.  This is something to advocate for; if you're a "Random Programmer" at the startup you want to try to wangle yourself into a higher title if you're being bought by a bigger company.

You will not be given any lump-sum money outside of this.

If your "exit" is a private equity company, you will probably get just about nothing unless you're a founder (and if you were a founder you wouldn't have this question, so...).

Is it "fair"?  That's a cosmic question.  It's customary, at least - you can't win the lottery without buying a ticket, and those equity shares are your lottery tickets.  "All you hard work" gets you only whatever they have given you in the past. That's not really fair in a larger sense, but until someone starts a revolution and we get to put some 1%ers up against the wall, that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

> What compensation should I expect not including equity I was given
>   when joined the company, if any?

Since compensation other than equity wasn't mentioned in your contract, you should expect nothing other than your equity converting to equity in the acquiring company

> And if I am offered such compensation, how can I evaluate whether it's
>   fair for me as an employee?

If you expect nothing, then anything above that should be more than fair.

If somehow you set your sights on something other than converted equity you risk disappointment. In that case, you'll need to decide how you feel at that point in time. There's no way someone other than you could gauge that ahead of time.